# Pass from a Binding<String> TextField to a Binding<Int> in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm developing a SwiftUI app and I want to recreate the effect of passing from a textField to the following one and, to do that, I need to wrap a TextField from UIKit which has the keyboard option "next" and "done".

I've this situation: 1 TextField (SwiftUI style) which accepts only a String and two TextFields (wrapped from UIKit) which accepts only Ints.
My aim is to make the TextField Binding the first responder of the View and connect the key "next" pressed by the user to the first TextField Binding and, thereafter, the second textField  Binding.

I've tried to implement the Binding inside the wrapper but I've got some problems because I don't know how to fill the init inside the View with the proper bindings.

I would really appreciate some help!

```
struct LinkedTextFields: View {

@State var name : String = ""
@State var number_1 : Int = 100
@State var number_2 : Int = 10
@State var focused: [Bool] = [true, false, false]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    HStack {
                        Text("Number 1:")
                        Spacer()
                        TextFieldWrapped(keyboardType: .namePhonePad, returnVal: .next, tag: 0, number: self.$number_1, isfocusAble: self.$focused)
                    }


                    HStack {
                        Text("Number 2:")
                        Spacer()
                        TextFieldWrapped(keyboardType: .namePhonePad, returnVal: .done, tag: 1, number: self.$number_2, isfocusAble: self.$focused)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Add product")
    }
}
}



struct TextFieldWrapped: UIViewRepresentable {

let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
let returnVal: UIReturnKeyType
let tag: Int
@Binding var number: Int
@Binding var isfocusAble: [Bool]


func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
    textField.keyboardType = self.keyboardType
    textField.returnKeyType = self.returnVal
    textField.tag = self.tag
    textField.delegate = context.coordinator
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    textField.textAlignment = .center
    return textField
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
    if isfocusAble[tag] {
        uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        uiView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    uiView.text = String(number)
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self, $number)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var parent: TextFieldWrapped
    var number: Binding<Int>

    init(_ textField: TextFieldWrapped,_ number: Binding<Int>) {
        self.parent = textField
        self.number = number
    }

    func updatefocus(textfield: UITextField) {
        textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if parent.tag == 0 {
            parent.isfocusAble = [false, true]
            parent.number = Int(textField.text ?? "") ?? 0
        }
        else if parent.tag == 1 {
            parent.isfocusAble = [false, false]
            parent.number = Int(textField.text ?? "") ?? 0
        }
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
        if reason == .committed {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let text = textField.text as NSString?
        let newValue = text?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        if let number = Int(newValue ?? "0") {
            self.number.wrappedValue = number
            return true
        } else {
            if nil == newValue || newValue!.isEmpty {
                self.number.wrappedValue = 1
            }
            return false
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: "but I've got some problems" please be more concrete than that. What exact problems are you running into? Also, why are you mixing SwiftUI `TextField`s and `UITextField`s?

Comment: I've updated the post with more information